# .htaccess redirect based on a certain url param that redirects to another site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

I'm trying to set up a .htaccess redirect based on a certain url param, which then redirects to another site.

Example:

**Original URL**: www.domain.com/?param=true

**Redirected URL**: www.newdomain.com

I've tried many different approaches, but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work from site root .htaccess of `www.domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?param=true[&\s]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/? [L,R=301]
```